# Веб браузер с функцией "копировать весь текст и вставить в Word"

Tags: c#

Нужно скопировать все содержимое сайта (конкретнее, текст) и отправить в документ Word, а потом зайти на другую страницу, скопировать и послать в тот же самый документ Word. И чтобы копирование и вставка в Word происходили одним щелчком по кнопке.

Копирование текста:

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText);
}
```

Копируется вся страница, и когда в Word вставляется документ, то формат меняется: там на странице таблица, и в Word все показывается вперемешку. Как сохранить формат?

Создание и открытие документа Word:

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

    op.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    op.Filter = "Word document (*.docx)|*.docx";

    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Object fileName = op.FileName;
        Word.Application appl = new Word.Application();

        if (appl != null)
        {
            Object missing = Type.Missing;
            Object @false = false;    
            appl.Documents.Open(ref fileName ...); // ... - остальные аргументы    
            appl.Visible = true;
        }
        else  
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Word не запущен");
        }
    }
}
```

После того, как документ откроется, я нажимаю другую кнопку, чтоб вставить туда текст, который находится в `Clipboard`. Вот код:

```
private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = appl.ActiveDocument;

    object start = 0;
    object end = doc.Content.End;

    doc.Range(ref start, ref end).InsertAfter(Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

Здесь проблема. Выдает ошибку. Так как appl не определен. Я не хочу каждый раз открывать Ворд документ, вставлять туда текст и закрывать. Одной кнопкой выбрать Ворд документ, запустить его, а другой кнопкой (`toolStripButton3_Click`) занести это все в документ. Как это реализовать? Как сделать, чтобы он работал с документом, который открыт другой кнопкой? Сам appl в другой кнопке определен, но в `toolStripButton3_Click` его не видно.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сохранить формат?

Чтобы передавался не простой текст, а отформатированный, нужно использовать пару методов:

- [GetText(TextDataFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/944ft9kf.aspx)
- [SetText(String, TextDataFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tbfb3z56.aspx)

> Как сделать, чтобы он работал с документом, который открыт другой кнопкой?

Нужно сделать переменную **appl** членом класса, тогда она станет видимой во всех нестатических методах класса. Это даст возможность, открыв документ в одном методе, положить содержимое буфера обмена в документ в другом методе.